# Does endwin() de-initialize ncurses?

Tags: ncurses

I am using the `ncurses` library to show some funny output on the screen, but in the middle of the program I need to temporarily exit `ncurses` mode. I call `endwin()`, after which my program should be able to use `printf()` to show a menu to the user. Unluckily, my program was unable to show the menu. I tried using  `fflush()` after `printf()`, and only then is it able to show the menu on the screen.

Can anyone tell me why, after I call `endwin()`, the terminal can't return to normal and I'm unable to use `printf()`?

Answer (score 0):

Use `def_prog_mode` prior to `endwin` to save state.
After returning, do: `reset_prog_mode` and then `refresh`.
Your original screen will be shown.

Yes, after using printf you have to do: fflush(stdout).